# Java: how to specify relative file path?

Tags: java, filepath

You know when you look inside games and you see folders with the pictures, music, audio effects, etc.?
How can Java know how to find these files inside the folders if the absolute file path changes with each different computer?

Comment: Your title is completely different than the body of your question.

Comment: What have you tried until now?

Comment: Provide some code. I need to know what I am looking at...

Comment: It's actually your program that needs to know, or to figure it out.  If the location of the file is completely variable, then it must be provided by the user of your program.  Your title suggests the file possibly has a fixed relationship to the location of your program and/or the Java virtual machine (so a hardwired relative path could work) but that seems improbable as a general case.

Comment: basically the program that you install created all the files depending on the path you give it at the start so it also knows where it created them , he other option is using environment variables for example JAVA_HOME is a environment variables that points to the installation directory of java

Answer (score 1):

That really depends on the application you are developing. The start location is usually the path of your project and from that point, you can define a relative path to whatever file you are looking for. Using this idea, you can infer that application developers prefer to use relative paths to be able to execute the application in different devices. However, how a relative path is defined can change between different platforms.

Comment: I was about to write something similar but in a more confusing way since I'm not good with words. Thank you for beating me to it. :'D